# How to hide three dots underlining macro names in Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: visual-studio

Every use of any macro names in my projects gets underlined with 3 dots:
[image]

When I hover mouse over it , I get a light bulb and small msg box saying that browsing around this identifier may be incorrect and suggest to add this macro to a hint file, which doesn't seem to do anything:

[image]

Anyone knows how to get rid of the dots ?

Comment: Does anything happen if you point mouse cursor on it?

Comment: If you hover over the stipple, there should be a tooltip telling you why it's there. If you click on the stipple, an icon should appear to the left for further options. It's hard to give anything more specific without knowing why they're there.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I've edited the post to add more info, and will edit more if more questions come

Answer (score 2):

Finally after multiple attempts of "staring at the screen" problem solving method I found a way to turn the dots off. In "Tools->Options" menu navigate to "Text Editor->C/C++->View" and in the drop-down box "Macros in skipped browsing regions" select "none".